# UITableView reloadRows crashes sometime

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloadrows

I have 4 rows which shows and hide some data below the selected row. Its works fine Most of the time. But when I click second/third/fourth rows multiple times(like 13-14) times and then click on first row then sometime it crashes not always but it crashes most of the time after multiple clicks. I am changing row height as well. Crash only happen when I select first row(case a), after selecting other rows multiple times. Below is my code -

I tried multiple things like calling it between beginUpdate and endUpdate, check is indexPath exist before reloading

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ”cell”, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        let model = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.model = model

        switch model.type {
        case .a:
            cell.aList = savedCardList
            cell.addACallback = {[weak self] (sender) in
                self?.moveToAVC()
            }
            cell.addACallback= {[weak self] (a) in
                self?.selectedA = a
                self?.updateButton()
            }

        case .b:
            cell.bList = bList
            cell.bSelectedCallback = {[weak self] (bInfo) in
                self?.selectedB= bInfo
                self?.updateButton()
            }

        case .c:
            cell.cList = cList
            if let cInfo = selectedC {
                cell.selectOtherCButton.setTitle(cInfo.name, for: .normal)
            }
            cell.selectOtherCCallback = {[weak self] (sender) in
                self?.showSelectCVC()
            }
            cell.CSelectedCallback = {[weak self] (cInfo) in
                self?.selectedC = cInfo
                self?.updateButton()
            }

        case .d:
            cell.dTextField.text = dString
            cell.dChangedCallBack = {[weak self] (textField) in
                if let dStr = textField.text {
                    self?.dString = dStr
                }
                self?.updateButton()
            }

        default:
            break
        }
        return cell
    }


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let model = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        guard model.isSelected == true else {
            return 90
        }
        switch model.type {
        case .a:
            if aList.count > 0 {
                return 350
            }
            return 140

        case .b:
            return 200

        case .c:
            return 270

        case .d:
            return 130

        default:
            return 90
        }
    }


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let model = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        selectedType = model.type
        updateButtonState(false)
        updateButton()

        if let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath, selectedIndexPath != indexPath {
            self.updatemodelSelectedState(false, at: selectedIndexPath)
            self.updatemodelSelectedState(true, at: indexPath)
            if let _ = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath), let _ = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) {
                self.reloadTableViewRows([selectedIndexPath, indexPath])
                tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
            }
        }
        else if !model.isSelected {
            self.updatemodelSelectedState(true, at: indexPath)
                if let _ = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
                    self.reloadTableViewRows([indexPath])
                }
        }
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }

 private func reloadTableViewRows(_ indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
            self.myTableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
            self.myTableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
```

Xcode console log(I am only getting this one liner) -

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

It crashes at self.myTableView.endUpdates() this line. If I remove begin and end updates then it crashes at  self.myTableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic). Also for one of the row I show a popup on a button click and after then if I select my first row, it crashes!

Also I have collection view inside table view rows which I am hiding and showing. Even though its flow is set to horizontal, after multiple clicks once in a while I notice that collection view rows comes in vertical flow and then in next click it gets back to horizontal flow again. Not sure why this is happening but could this be issue?

Please help. I am trying to resolve this issue from last 2-3 hours :(

Comment: Show the crash log that is printed in the console.

Comment: try the following. `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPaths], with: .automatic)`

Comment: @PGDev I have updated the crash log in the question

Comment: @RichaSrivastava please check the console once again, there might be more than one line in the error log

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem statement that you're trying to solve. There might be another way to do that.

Comment: @RichaSrivastava try removing scrollToRowAt after reloadRows

Comment: @SahilManchanda Even I don't understand why it only gives one line of error. I have checked my console properly there is only one line of error. My exception breakpoint stops at reloadRow and then crashes.

Comment: @PGDev I have 4 rows which shows and hide some data below the selected row.  Its works fine Most of the time. But when I click second/third/fourth rows multiple times(like 13-14) times and then click on first row then sometime it crashes not always but it crashes most of the time after multiple clicks.

Comment: @ShivamGaur I have tried that but then also it crashes.

Comment: @RichaSrivastava You need to update your question to match the comment you have said regarding having 4 rows and how you are getting to crash.

Comment: @RichaSrivastava you might have done this but to be sure, do select the exception breakpoint ,(Steps -> Debug - BreakPoints - Create Exception BreakPoint) , it might give you more insight to the crash.

Comment: @ShivamGaur Yes! I have done that. It stops at reloadRows line and then crashes with only one line of error

Answer (score -1):

**Try This one i hope it will be work for you:**

```
   UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
   tableView.beginUpdates()
   tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)
   tableView.endUpdates()
   UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Its still crashing but this time it took longer to reproduce the crash. after selecting between all the row for around 20 times it crashed

Comment: I have collection view inside table view rows which I am hiding and showing. Even though its flow is set to horizontal, after multiple clicks once in a while I notice that collection view rows comes in vertical flow and then in next click it gets back to horizontal flow again. Not sure why this is happening but could this be issue?